# Add Objects Properties - JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Trying to wrap properties of `activatedItems` and `quarterItems` into one object i.e., `modules`.

```
{
  "isExternalVisitor": false,
  "isAdmin": true,
  "modules": [
    {
      "moduleId": "4c4fd9c9",
      "code": "GOT-Q1-1",
      "siteId": "90837854",
      "activatedId": "765abf85",
      "flowId": "71170cf1",
      "status": 3
    },
    {
      "moduleId": "ac3511c1",
      "code": "FOOD-Q3-1",
      "siteId": "90837854",
      "activatedId": "2263c865",
      "flowId": "4b6cfed4",
      "status": 3
    },
    {
      "moduleId": "5e58d975",
      "code": "FOOD12-Q3-1",
      "siteId": "5826e23f",
      "activatedId": "30323e25",
      "flowId": "72800237",
      "status": 3
    },
    {
      "moduleId": "3f2e7c3c",
      "code": "GOT31-Q1-1",
      "siteId": "6010c42d",
      "activatedId": "84227a10",
      "flowId": "08734f4b",
      "status": 3
    }
  ],
   "activatedItems": [
    {
      "activatedId": "765abf85",
      "siteId": "90837854",
      "stQuarterId": "bdea473a",
      "checklistId": "b89f1512-2805-4e70-ac91-1710e9b80007"
    },
    {
      "activatedId": "30323e25",
      "siteId": "5826e23f",
      "stQuarterId": "25a363f6",
      "checklistId": "447c54fc-3541-45af-a96b-d49ccb46d33a"
    },
    {
      "activatedId": "2263c865",
      "siteId": "90837854",
      "stQuarterId": "25a363f6",
      "checklistId": "447c54fc-3541-45af-a96b-d49ccb46d33a"
    },
    {
      "activatedId": "84227a10",
      "siteId": "6010c42d",
      "stQuarterId": "bdea473a",
      "checklistId": "b89f1512-2805-4e70-ac91-1710e9b80007"
    }
  ],
  "quarterItems": [
    {
      "id": "bdea473a",
      "checklistId": "b89f1512-2805-4e70-ac91-1710e9b80007",
      "fullName": "GOT",
      "year": "2021-01-01T00:00:00",
      "quarter": "2021-Q1",
      "versions": 1,
      "activated": true
    },
    {
      "id": "25a363f6",
      "checklistId": "447c54fc-3541-45af-a96b-d49ccb46d33a",
      "fullName": "FOOD",
      "year": "2021-01-01T00:00:00",
      "quarter": "2021-Q3",
      "versions": 2,
      "activated": true
    }
  ]
}
```

This is the expected result where only one object has got all the data.

```
{
  "isExternalVisitor": false,
  "isAdmin": true,
  "modules": [
    {
      "moduleId": "4c4fd9c9",
      "code": "GOT-Q1-1",
      "siteId": "90837854",
      "activatedId": "765abf85",
      "flowId": "71170cf1",
      "status": 3,
      "stQuarterId": "bdea473a",
      "checklistId": "b89f1512-2805-4e70-ac91-1710e9b80007",
       "fullName": "GOT",
      "year": "2021-01-01T00:00:00",
      "quarter": "2021-Q1",
      "versions": 1,
      "activated": true
    },
    {
      "moduleId": "ac3511c1",
      "code": "FOOD-Q3-1",
      "siteId": "90837854",
      "activatedId": "2263c865",
      "flowId": "4b6cfed4",
      "status": 3,
      "stQuarterId": "25a363f6",
      "checklistId": "447c54fc-3541-45af-a96b-d49ccb46d33a",
      "fullName": "FOOD",
      "year": "2021-01-01T00:00:00",
      "quarter": "2021-Q3",
      "versions": 2,
      "activated": true
    },
    {
      "moduleId": "5e58d975",
      "code": "FOOD12-Q3-1",
      "siteId": "5826e23f",
      "activatedId": "30323e25",
      "flowId": "72800237",
      "status": 3,
      "stQuarterId": "25a363f6",
      "checklistId": "447c54fc-3541-45af-a96b-d49ccb46d33a",
      "fullName": "FOOD",
      "year": "2021-01-01T00:00:00",
      "quarter": "2021-Q3",
      "versions": 2,
      "activated": true
    },
    {
      "moduleId": "3f2e7c3c",
      "code": "GOT31-Q1-1",
      "siteId": "6010c42d",
      "activatedId": "84227a10",
      "flowId": "08734f4b",
      "status": 3,
      "stQuarterId": "bdea473a",
      "checklistId": "b89f1512-2805-4e70-ac91-1710e9b80007",
       "fullName": "GOT",
      "year": "2021-01-01T00:00:00",
      "quarter": "2021-Q1",
      "versions": 1,
      "activated": true
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried the following and was able to merge them in one array, but however, the end result is not the same as above. Your kind help will be appreciated.

```
 const result = {
                        isExternalVisitor: response.result.isExternalVisitor,
                        isAdmin: response.result.isAdmin
                    };
                    result.modules = response.result.modules.map((el, i) => ({
                        ...el,
                        ...response.result.activatedItems[i],
                        ...response.result.quarterItems[i]
                    }));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Array.map` implementation

**Logic**

- Generate basic output array with keys `isExternalVisitor` and `isAdmin` with values from `data` object.
- Modules data of the output array is generated by clubbing 3 objects. Node from `modules` array, node from `activatedItems` array with matching key from the object in `modules` array (key `activatedId`). Find the node with that matching condition. That matching node will return an object that has the key to node from `quarterItems` array (key is `stQuarterId`). Collect these three objects, merge them to form one singlr object and push that to `modules` array of output. I used `Array.map` for this

```js
const data = {
  "isExternalVisitor": false,
  "isAdmin": true,
  "modules": [
    {
      "moduleId": "4c4fd9c9",
      "code": "GOT-Q1-1",
      "siteId": "90837854",
      "activatedId": "765abf85",
      "flowId": "71170cf1",
      "status": 3
    },
    {
      "moduleId": "ac3511c1",
      "code": "FOOD-Q3-1",
      "siteId": "90837854",
      "activatedId": "2263c865",
      "flowId": "4b6cfed4",
      "status": 3
    },
    {
      "moduleId": "5e58d975",
      "code": "FOOD12-Q3-1",
      "siteId": "5826e23f",
      "activatedId": "30323e25",
      "flowId": "72800237",
      "status": 3
    },
    {
      "moduleId": "3f2e7c3c",
      "code": "GOT31-Q1-1",
      "siteId": "6010c42d",
      "activatedId": "84227a10",
      "flowId": "08734f4b",
      "status": 3
    }
  ],
  "activatedItems": [
    {
      "activatedId": "765abf85",
      "siteId": "90837854",
      "stQuarterId": "bdea473a",
      "checklistId": "b89f1512-2805-4e70-ac91-1710e9b80007"
    },
    {
      "activatedId": "30323e25",
      "siteId": "5826e23f",
      "stQuarterId": "25a363f6",
      "checklistId": "447c54fc-3541-45af-a96b-d49ccb46d33a"
    },
    {
      "activatedId": "2263c865",
      "siteId": "90837854",
      "stQuarterId": "25a363f6",
      "checklistId": "447c54fc-3541-45af-a96b-d49ccb46d33a"
    },
    {
      "activatedId": "84227a10",
      "siteId": "6010c42d",
      "stQuarterId": "bdea473a",
      "checklistId": "b89f1512-2805-4e70-ac91-1710e9b80007"
    }
  ],
  "quarterItems": [
    {
      "id": "bdea473a",
      "checklistId": "b89f1512-2805-4e70-ac91-1710e9b80007",
      "fullName": "GOT",
      "year": "2021-01-01T00:00:00",
      "quarter": "2021-Q1",
      "versions": 1,
      "activated": true
    },
    {
      "id": "25a363f6",
      "checklistId": "447c54fc-3541-45af-a96b-d49ccb46d33a",
      "fullName": "FOOD",
      "year": "2021-01-01T00:00:00",
      "quarter": "2021-Q3",
      "versions": 2,
      "activated": true
    }
  ]
}

const output = {
  isExternalVisitor: data.isExternalVisitor,
  isAdmin: data.isAdmin,
};

output.modules = data.modules.map((node) => {
  const activatedItemsNode = data.activatedItems.find((item) => item.activatedId === node.activatedId);
  const quarterItemsNode = data.quarterItems.find((item) => item.id === activatedItemsNode.stQuarterId);
  const mergedNode = { ...node, ...activatedItemsNode, ...quarterItemsNode };
  return mergedNode;
});
console.log(JSON.stringify(output));
```

Answer (score 0):

To merge both items you'd do

```
[...response.result.activatedItems, ...response.result.quarterItems]
```

Not sure how where you'd want to add that back into your `result` object.